# Why was my post about ColdFusion deleted?

Tags: support, specific-question

Why was my post, ["does anybody can provide me ColdFusion 4.5 version, both server and studio? "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362715), deleted?????

Comment: Which post are you referring to?

Comment: God hates ColdFusion.

Comment: Thank you, TheTXI for officially recognizing my status a god.

Comment: Because you were asking for a copy of copyrighted software, which you should buy and not try to get someone else to "provide" it to you. Someone even posted this helpful link: http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_i_1?rh=i:software,k:coldfusion+4.5&keywords=coldfusion+4.5&ie=UTF8&qid=1251814423

Comment: @Joachim Saucer: Why are you making a perfectly legitimate answer into a comment?

Comment: Who uses ColdfFusion anyway?

Answer (score 7):

I deleted them after it attracted a *considerable* number of spam flags and moderator flags in a very short space of time. To be honest, it was on the brink of being auto-deleted by the system (spam/offensive flags); I just gave it a small helping nudge.

In particular, you are asking people to contact you by e-mail to obtain a copy of software that you should *buy*.

Comment: that's a no no.

Comment: +                             1

Comment: Good call on the lock.

Comment: Contact by email is bad. Well done. However, since Adobe is giving away a free version of ColdFusion, the question would be legitimate. (If only the Q had mentioned that Adobe is giving away free versions.)

Answer (score 3):

What you were asking for was also sort of illegal in these here United States. Try [searching Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_i_1?rh=i:software,k:coldfusion+4.5&keywords=coldfusion+4.5&ie=UTF8&qid=1251814423) to find it (one of your posts had that as an answer), and then, you know, fracking buy the damned thing.

Comment: +1, but you could be wrong. Adobe is giving away a developer version of version 8 away for free. I think they also gave away a version of 4.5 away for free, thus the Q would be okay as long as it's about this specific free product, not the commercial version.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking people whose salaries are paid through software licensing fees to help you steal software. You might as well just ask for donations.

Answer (score 2):

[Found it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362920/does-anyone-have-coldfusion4-5-server-and-studio-software-closed). And the [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362715).

These were closed since they are not programming related. But relate to obtaining software.

Comment: Page not found for mere mortals.

Comment: @Randell: muahahahaha! Uhm ... yes, it's only visible with 10k rep, I think. He was asking for someone to email him if they can "provide" him Coldfusion 4.5, claiming he didn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the request was for an illegal version of ColdFusion or a request for an abandoned version of ColdFusion. I've used ColdFusion myself in the past, somewhere in 200, right before MacroMedia took over Allaire. Version 4.5 would be about 10 years old now, so you could wonder if people are still supposed to pay for it's license... 
Now MacroMedia is owned by Adobe, which just adds another company as owner. And things have changed a bit ever since. Adove is giving away CF 8.0 for free for development purposes only at http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/downloads.html and no, that's the official site, not some illegal crack! Now, if the question was about such a developer version, but then an older version number, the question would be perfectly legal, although a bit spamlike...

For an antique version of ColdFusion, best thing to do is to contact Adobe and ask them if they can provide you such an antique version. Or be happy with the *free* 8.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  I checked eBay and the oldest ColdFusion I could find was version 7 (it's up to 9 or 10 now). Even that was over $1700.  No wonder no one uses it.

Comment: Not even God can afford ColdFusion.

Comment: Latest version is 8. Right now, 9 is still in development or about to be published. And 10 is still a wet dream for the developers at Adobe. :-)